# Can't convert OpenSSH private key to RSA

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, sftp, rsa

There are numerous sources online [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994641/openssh-private-key-to-rsa-private-key) that say an OpenSSH private key:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNz....blah etc....DBAUGBwgJ
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

can be converted to RSA format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNz....blah etc....DBAUGBwgJ
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

by using ssh-keygen, specifically:

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "my new pass phrase" -m pem -f my.key
```

where `my.key` is the file containing the OpenSSH private key (the -N option can be omitted if the pass phrase doesn't need to change)

The key file is supposed to get overwritten with an RSA key but for me it just doesn't work - the file does gets overwritten, but with another OpenSSH key.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm using Win 10.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for replying.  I discovered that the OpenSSH key I had was in Ed25519 format, and apparently that can't be converted to RSA, so I suspect that is the reason.  I think i'm going to have to generate a new key pair.